# UML Query for class diagram relationship

Tags: uml, relationship, class-diagram

A few query and opinions to seek on the best type of relationship and representation to be used in a class diagram for modelling with uml

1) Third party library used by my class
-- I have modeled them as packages

2) Wrapper Class to wrap around modified code
-- I have modeled this class as an interface

3) My wrapper class actually use non-class member function that is written in another namespace
-- This puzzled me. How should I modeled them?

4) For classes in my own created library(dll), how do i differentiate the class that is exported and those that is not

Thanks

Comment: Opinion based questions are likely to be closed by an admin...

Answer (score 1):

1) That's fine. However, it depends on the layer. I could think of a component to represent a library.

2) Not necessary. A wrapper inherits from a class. So use a generalization.

3) You can not really do that. You might use an artifact and a relation (association) to it.

4) I would use a component with interfaces (lollipops) to show the exported ones. The others are kept inside.

For all answers: YMMV